# Defining a function to determine if a file exists

Tags: python, pandas, import

I am pulling a dataset via an API. That dataset gets updated everyday. I need to pull the dataset return it to a csv and keep that version of the data pull. I believe the code should read something like the pseudocode below

```
def expull ()
if file exist expull.csv
return pd.read_csv(expull.csv)
else return usage_one():

def usage():
    sisense = Sisense({
           "host": getenv("SISENSE_HOST"),
           "api_user": getenv("SISENSE_API_USER_EMAIL"),
           "password": getenv("SISENSE_API_USER_PASSWORD")
})

  pd_results = sisense.sql('TPF',
                           """
                           SELECT....
                           )
 print(pd_results)
 pd_results save to csv expull.csv
 return pd_results
```

Comment: Are you asking how to write a pandas dataframe to a file for later use?  You can use any of the dataframe methods available in pandas like `.to_csv()`, `.to_parquet()`, `.to_pickle()`, etc.  Refer to pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same `random_state` input for the `.sample` to get the same result across multiple runs. This is called the "seed" of a random generator.